# Get/Set ToggleButton state in TableView JavaFX2.2

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

I am using TableView to display some data. Sample table is shown in the picture below:

[image: Editable TableView]

Only the items in 2nd column are editable. Third column contains a ToggleButton which basically displays the TextField when 'Edit' button is clicked.

What I want is to toggle the state of the corresponding ToggleButton in the following event handler function (See the comments in the code snippet below).

```
textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    //Toggle the state of Edit button here
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                    //Toggle the state of Edit button here
                }
            }
        });
```

I have tried my level best to get the corresponding edit button object in the selected row but nothing helped and I couldn't find any related article.

Is it something achievable? If so how can it be done.

Answer (score 0):

So, do I understand correctly, if the button `isSelected` you want to be able to edit the text field? So why not getting the `TextField` and the `ToggleButton` in your controller, attach an `OnAction`  method to your button and then change the text field to editable. Something like:

~Controller:

```
@FXML
private ToggleButton togglebutton;

@FXML
private TextField textfield;

@FXML
public void actionEditField(ActionEvent event) {
    if (togglebutton.isSelected()) {
        textfield.setEditable(true);
        ...
    } else {
        ...
        commitEdit(textfield.getText());
        textfield.setEditable(false);
        ...
    }
}
```

~ Fxml:

```
<ToggleButton fx:id="togglebutton" alignment="CENTER" onAction="#actionEditField" text="Edit" />
```

Would that help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you understood the problem correctly. However, these Edit buttons are created dynamically for every row. They are not created at design time so this solution won't help. The approach I've used to display buttons in the grid is similar to this article http://java-buddy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/javafx-embed-button-in-tableview.html